# Detecting the tapped segment of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, hide, uisegmentedcontrol

I have placed an UISegmentedControl into my XIB file. Basically, when the the second tab of the control is tapped (aka segment 1, the first segment is segment 0), I want to unhide a text field. I know how to unhide the text field, but how do I detect which part of the segmented control the user has tapped?

```
[textField setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should hook up your segmeted controls `valueChanged` action in IB to a method in your view controller that checks your segmented controls `selectedSegmentIndex`.

Answer (score 23):

Create an IBAction like the one below and connect it to the valueChanged action in Interface Builder.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender
{
   UISegmentedControl *s = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

   if (s.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
   {
      [countTextField setHidden:NO];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a target-action for the control event `UIControlEventValueChanged` and check the `selectedSegmentIndex` of the segmented control.

If it is `1` then hide the text field.